# a line break in a UITextField?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

is it possible to put a line break in a UITextField or would I have to use UITextView?

thanks

Comment: What platform? What language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would need to use the UITextView for line feeds. They seem to be ignored by UITextField.